# navigate to a method implementation by code eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, pde

I am developing a plugin.

I need your help. I have a Table with methods' names . I need go to the method's' implementation in the editor when I click on the method name. The table has the path of the file where method is implemented and the method's header.

I will thank you if you could help me with code so as to do it.

By now I have the code to open a file. But I need to open the method's implementantion in a file.

```
File fileToOpen = new File(file);
                if (fileToOpen.exists() && fileToOpen.isFile()) {
                    IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileToOpen.toURI());
                    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
                    try {
                    IEditorPart editor =IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);

                    } catch (PartInitException exf) {
                        // Put your exception handler here if you wish to
                    }
                }
```

Regards

Comment: Many editors don't really like files outside of the workspace like this and will not provide as much functionality. Use `IFile` and `FileEditorInput` if the files are in the workspace.

Comment: The files aren't in workspace.

I want to go to the specify line of a method in a file e.g. the method draw() of the file circle.java as the outline view does with the methods.

Comment: Well `JavaUI.revealInEditor(IEditorPart part, IJavaElement element)` will show a Java element, but that means you have to find the `IJavaElement` in the AST - not something I know anything much about.

Comment: @greg-449 could you give me a example of finding the `IJavaElement`? I am using javaparser.

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to be 'javaparser' The Eclipe JDT Java editor requires you to use the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: how do I look a method whith compilation unit if I have the header e.g. public Query buildQuery(String queryStr) throws ParseException  and the path of file

Comment: @greg-449 can you share me a example where I use the compilation unit to find the method by header and store it in a `iJavaElement`?

Comment: I already said I don't know anything about that

Comment: @greg-449 it could be with the ast that you meant above.